JIRA: Scriptrunner UI button on create page
What's the problem:
We need to add a UI button that fills the description text field with certain data, for now let this data be "test123" or any other.
This button should be located next to the description field.
How can I do this through Script runner?
I go to the UI Fragments -> Web Panel section, then select WikiRendererWebPanel in the Location, fill in all the other information New Element key = test1 and write the code from the tutorial in the Provider class/script.
writer.write("""
<div style='
    background-color: #ff0000; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    padding: 10px;  
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
'>
    test1.<br>
    test2.
</div>
""")

But when I go to the desired Jira project and click the Create button, there are no new elements on the page. But if you go into the DOM tree and search for the Menu text element, you can find it.
How do I add a UI button to the task creation page?
Maybe this should be done through the Web Item, and not through the Web Panel? But there is no create-issue-dialog element in the Web Item, or I don't understand something :(
Please help who owns Jira Scriptrunner :)
